# Ansible Mail Callback Plugin With Items

Tags: email, plugins, ansible, callback

I'm running Ansible 2.4.1.0.

I have the below but for some reason I'm not getting the expected behaviour.

Maybe I'm wrong or have assumed incorrectly?
I'm expecting the mail callback plugin to output the fail msg ("Ansible: Alert - Rogue Port {{ item }}").

Please can someone suggest a change or workaround?

---

```yaml
- name: check allowed ports
  tags: ports
  fail:
    msg: "Ansible: Alert - Rogue Port {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ ports_var.stdout_lines }}"
  failed_when:
    - "item not in ports_lookup_var"
```

As you can see below, no fail msg in the generated mail.

```
$> ansible-playbook playbooks/rpc.yml --limit=warp.?????.local --tags ports

TASK [check allowed ports] *****************************************************
failed: [warp.?????.local] (item=127.0.0.1:1196) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "failed_when_result": true, "item": "127.0.0.1:1196", "msg": "Ansible: Alert - Rogue Port 127.0.0.1:1196"}
ok: [warp.?????.local] => (item=*:22)
ok: [warp.?????.local] => (item=127.0.0.1:25)
ok: [warp.?????.local] => (item=127.0.0.1:8090)
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/ansible/playbooks/rpc.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
warp.gsoc.local            : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

The mail received.

```
Date: Thu, 14 Dec 2017 18:40:36 +0200 (SAST)
From: "Ansible: node03.??????.local" <root@ansible.?????.local>
To: root@ansible.??????.local
Subject: Failed: All items completed

Playbook: rpc.yml
Task: check allowed ports
Module: fail
Host: node03.???????.local

The following task failed:

        check allowed ports (fail)

with the following message:

        All items completed

A complete dump of the error:

        Failed: {"msg": "All items completed", "failed": true, "changed": false}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a mail plugin issue. This is how Ansible evaluates failures for tasks with loops.

I don’t see a reason for a loop here though — you can use the [`difference` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) to get a list of “rogue ports” and fail when that list is not empty.

The condition is:

```
ports_var.stdout_lines | difference(ports_lookup_var) | length > 0
```

And you can use the first part of the expression in a Jinja2 template to nicely format the error message (then using a loop, but inside the template); or simply convert the list to a string:

```yaml
fail:
  msg: "Ansible: Alert - Rogue Ports: {{ rogue_ports | join(', ') }}"
  when: rogue_ports | length > 0
  vars:
    rogue_ports: "{{ ports_var.stdout_lines | difference(ports_lookup_var) }}"
```

<sup>There are tools specifically created for compliance verification, Ansible might not be the best choice for such tasks.</sup>

Comment: Oh boy! Thank you kind sir. I don't understand how, but it works. I will have to go and read up on this to fully comprehend. I will take your advice into consideration WRT compliance tools etc.